# Get and pass the order ID on a custom payment gateway in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders

I am building custom payment gateway which i need to handle the success response through ajax and mapped the transaction id with the order id. I am querying to get the last_order_id. Is this the correct way to get the order id or any issue will be arised if i use this way to get the order id.

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",                                          
        url: 'http://example.com/?wc-api=callback',
// .........
</script>

function callback(){
    // handle the response here 
}


function get_last_order_id(){
    global $wpdb;
    $statuses = array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses());
    $statuses = implode( "','", $statuses );

    // Getting last Order ID (max value)
    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT MAX(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
        WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND post_status IN ('$statuses')
    " );
    return reset($results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

On **a normal process** you can see in [`WC_Checkout` Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html) on [`process_checkout()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html#_process_checkout) method:

```
$order_id = $this->create_order( $posted_data ); // on line 1067
```

or in [`WC_Checkout` Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html) with [`create_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html#_%20create_order) method:

```
$order_id = $order->save(); // on line 365
```

Which gives **the Order ID**

Now inside the [`process_checkout()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html#_process_checkout) method you have:

```
if ( WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) {
    $this->process_order_payment( $order_id, $posted_data['payment_method'] );
```

And if you look to [`process_order_payment()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#786-817) you will see:

```
// Store Order ID in session so it can be re-used after payment failure
WC()->session->set( 'order_awaiting_payment', $order_id );
```

which **will store the order ID in Woocommerce sessions**

> So **TO GET THE ORDER ID** through AJAX *(when it has been generated)* you will use inside your Wordpress Ajax PHP function:
>
> ```
> $order_id = WC()->session->get( 'order_awaiting_payment' );
> ```
>
> And return it to jQuery.

Comment: actually i need the order id before payment process because my payment gateway send the reponse in javascript have to map the order id on submit through jquery

Comment: already my order id is created at the backedn i need to get the order id in this funciton jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function () { })